# Не работает событие отпускание пальца на мобильном устройстве

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Вот макет

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При наведении на "Смотреть проект" эта ссылка выезжает влево и высвечивает ссылку "Дополнительно". Но на мобильном устройстве при нажатии пальцем на "Смотреть проект" происходит событие нажатия на ссылку "Смотреть проект" соответственно, и выбрать и нажать на ссылку "Дополнительно" не возможно. Нужна возможность "выбрать на какую ссылку нужно нажать". Как реализовать такой функционал для мобильных устройств.

Вот HTML

```
<p class="show_link_wrapp"><a href="#" class="show_link">Смотреть проект</a><a href="#" class="add_link">Дополнительно</a></p>
```

Вот CSS

```
.show_link_wrapp {
    padding-right: 0;
}

.show_link_wrapp .show_link {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}

.show_link_wrapp .add_link {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 5px;
    right: 0;
}

.show_link_wrapp:hover {
    padding-right: 176px;
}
```

Вот JS который я начал писать. Если есть решения лучше - то пожалуйста предложите.

```
  if (/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|BB|PlayBook|IEMobile|Windows Phone|Kindle|Silk|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {

      $(".show_link_wrapp")
      .mousedown()(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).addClass("over");
      })
      .mouseleave(function() {
        $(this).removeClass("over");
      });
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скобки после mousedown уберите

```
  if (/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|BB|PlayBook|IEMobile|Windows Phone|Kindle|Silk|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {

      $(".show_link_wrapp")
      .mousedown(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).addClass("over");
      })
      .mouseleave(function() {
        $(this).removeClass("over");
      });
  }
```